# replacing a bunch of href with jquery. need just code improvement

Tags: javascript, jquery, href, each, attr

I try to change the href of 3 a-tags with jquery. 
At the moment, I do that with normal javascript.

```
var catNav = $('ul.nav'),
newLink = ['new1/','new2','nwe3/'];

catNav.attr('id','node');
var node =document.getElementById('node');
for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
node.childNodes[i].firstChild.href=newLink[i];
}
```

what i want from you. just teach me how i do this

```
for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
    node.childNodes[i].firstChild.href=newLink[i];
}
```

with jquery.

here's an example
http://jsfiddle.net/HFj2D/1/

Comment: Without more details, this would be the correct non-bloated jQuery way to do it: `$('#node > * > a').each(function(i){this.href = newLink[i]});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the whole thing:

```
var newLink = ['new1/','new2','nwe3/'];

$("ul.nav").attr('id', 'node').find('a').each(function(index, el) {
    this.href = newLink[index];
});
```

Ideally you should already have an ID on the `<ul>` tag anyway, though.

Comment: hey guys, thx for your help. and thx to alnitak and felix kling. 
this is the final code
http://jsfiddle.net/HFj2D/7/

this one is really good, because i dont use the underperformand .each(); function

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`attr` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$('ul.nav > li').slice(0,3).children('a:first-child').attr('href', function(i) {
    return newLink[i];
});
```

I also tried to select the elements the same way you did with plain JavaScript, i.e. the first three list entries and the first `a` element.

That said, if your array contains as many new links as you have `a` elements in your menu, then you can simplify the selection to:

```
$('ul.nav a').attr('href', /*...*/);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HFj2D/3/)

Comment: good call on the function-based version of `.attr` - I always forget that one exists.

Answer (score 1):

This will find all of the links beneath the catNav node (you already have the node), and assign the new href for each.

```
catNav.find('a').each(function(index) { $(this).attr('href', newLink[index]); })
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be:

```
for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
    $(node, ':nth-child(' + i + ')').children().first().attr('href', newLink[i]);
}
```

Comment: you have your selector and context arguments the wrong way around.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/HFj2D/2/

```
$.each($("#node").find("a"), function(i, link){
  $(link).attr("a", newLink[i]);
});
```

Comment: 1.  what's the "a" attr?  2.  `link` === `this`, so just use `this.href`, not `$(this).attr('href')`.

Comment: Good catch.  That's a typo.  Kudos to you for catching it amidst a sea of viable answers in a wholly uninteresting question thread :)

Answer (score 0):

`$(node).find('li a').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('href', 'newlink');
});`